# Magento Extension "Amazon Sales Channel" Not importing photos

Tags: magento2

I have Amazon Sales Channel installed on my Magento 2.3.3 CE store. Im using it to install and sync my amazon store with over 170,000 used books. My problem is that its not importing the photos. Any ideas?